# Android ConstraintLayout View to right of other View, but stay inside parent bounds

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I got two `TextViews` inside a `ConstraintLayout`. One on top left, the other to the right of the first one. Nothing crazy. Now, the first view can grow wider which pushes the second view more to the right. What I want though is that the second view always stays within the bounds of the parent.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingStart="20dp"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:paddingEnd="20dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text 1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:background="#FF0000"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/text1"
    android:text="Text 2"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:background="#00FF00"/>

    ...
```

What I get is something like this
[image]

But when I increase the text length, the second view is being pushed out of the view
[image]

What should happen is that the second view is on top right of the parent and the first one takes the rest of the available space. Is there any way I can do this in a `ConstraintLayout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `android:maxWidth` in the `activity_main.xml` with a fixed number, but it is not good because every phone has diffirent screen size, so I recommend you set it with code, you can `setMaxWidth` for `text1` following width of `text2` and `constraintLayout`:

```
        txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
        constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);

        ViewTreeObserver vto = constraintLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    constraintLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    constraintLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                }
                int text2Width = txt2.getWidth();
                int layoutWidth = constraintLayout.getWidth();
                txt1.setMaxWidth(layoutWidth-text2Width);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Yes that should work. But I was hoping for a solution that can be done only in the layout file... :-(

Comment: Marking this as correct answer since I could not find a better solution

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see to do this in constraintLayout is to make the 2 textView's a chain and apply `layout_constrainedWidth` to the first text view so the second text view gets priority:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:background="#fff"
    tools:layout_width="200dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Text 1"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/text2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Text 2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/text1" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Short Text 1:

[image: Short Text 1]

Long Text 1:

[image: Long Text 1]